# Excluding specific rows

Tags: r, rows

I have managed to manipulate part of my data set to exclude all percentage cover values of 0, but now am looking at excluding certain quadrats from certain years that don't have ash present in them. I was wondering if there was a specific way of specifying which quadrats I wanted removed from which year as opposed to deleting the quadrats from all the years, which is not what I want to do.

[image]

Comment: Could you show which column indicates `ash` presence/absence? And could you mentioned some examples of rows in this data that should be excluded based on the ash absence?

Comment: @AbdurRohman ash is indicated within the CommonName coloumn with all the other species within the quadrat present so i was hoping to exclude the quadrats which dont have ash inside - so in the image i would like rows 616-622 to go because that quadrat (Quadrat 91) for 2020 does not have ash present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your data is not in a text form, here is a very simple mock data that represents the case adequately:

```
dat <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
                 class = c("B", "A", "B", "B", "C", "B", "B", "C", "C")), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

dat
#    id class
# 1  1     B
# 2  1     A
# 3  1     B
# 4  2     B
# 5  2     C
# 6  2     B
# 7  3     B
# 8  3     C
# 9  3     C
```

Suppose I want to exclude any `id` that does not have `C` value in its `class`. So, the rows 1,2,3 should be excluded. One of the simplest way is to use `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
dat |> group_by(id) |> filter("C" %in% class)

#The result:

# A tibble: 6 × 2
# Groups:   id [2]
#     id class
#  <int> <chr>
#1     2 B    
#2     2 C    
#3     2 B    
#4     3 B    
#5     3 C    
#6     3 C
```

Note that the logic is that, because I want to *exclude* the group that *does not have* `C`, it means I want to *keep* the group that *has* `C`.

Hence `%in%` is used. It is a function that checks if a particular pattern matches a table. The pattern in this case is `C` and the table is the values in `class` column. I want to apply this function to each group of id, so `group_by(id)` is used.

Therefore, these steps can be applied to your data in this way:

```
yourdf |> group_by(Quadrat) |> filter("Ash" %in% CommonName)
```

### A base R option

In case you want to do the steps above in the base R, here is an option:

```
dat |> 
  by(dat$id,function(x) x["C" %in% x$class,])|> 
  do.call(rbind, args = _)

#     id class
# 2.4  2     B
# 2.5  2     C
# 2.6  2     B
# 3.7  3     B
# 3.8  3     C
# 3.9  3     C
```